# Selected a random number from a set

Tags: javascript, random

I want to select a random number out of a set. For example from the set {8, 6, 1, 7}.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.Random * 8);`

Comment: What does "I need select random in 8, 6, 1, 7 numbers" mean? Do you want to pick one out of the four numbers at random?

Comment: Canonical: [How get random item from es6 Map or Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739256/how-get-random-item-from-es6-map-or-set) (assuming you mean an [ES6 `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use following function to get a random number out of a set:

```
function getRndmFromSet(set)
{
    var rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * set.length);
    return set[rndm];
}
```

in your case the call would be `getRndmFromSet([8,6,1,7])`

Try the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VFQwL/)

**Note**: if your "set" is actually a `Set` object and not an array, you'd use `.size` instead of `.length`.

Comment: There's more to it than `.size` instead of `length`. You'll need to [turn the set into an array first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42739372/6243352).

Answer (score 1):

```
var range = [8, 6, 1, 7],
    rNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*range.length)%range.length,
    number = range[rNumber];
```

Comment: you don't need `%range.length` at the end since you multiply `[0,1)` by `range.length`, which would result in `[0,range.length)`, the floor of that is [0,range.length-1], and using `%range.length` you got the same as without.