# How do I get a random item from a JavaScript Set without using an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

Given a Set such as:

```
const mySet = new Set()
mySet.add(1)
mySet.add(2)
mySet.add(3)
```

How do I get a random item from this Set without first converting it to an array? Other answers to similar questions first converts the Set to an array. I was wondering if I could do without this conversion?

Comment: Would this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42739256/11398865

Comment: What is the intention behind the wish/requirement of not converting it into an array?

Comment: You can't `Set`  or `Map`are designed for random access. If you want random access then you have to convert it to an array.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I am trying to achieve a time complexity of O(1). First converting the Set to an array would give a time complexity of O(N) which I don't want

Comment: @Roi No it doesn't unfortunately. In that thread the Set is first converted to an array which I am avoiding